# Select statement where joins causing records to be excluded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query with multiple joins.The last 3 joins are required to get the g.fin_id value. This works fine (see results) BUT because some records in the ACCUM_ISS_CHAR_HIST table have e.char9_nme values of NULL, it excludes the records in the results altogether. So it seems as when the e.char9_nme value has a record then it will produce a result, but as soon as it has a Null value then it is excluded. I would still like to see the records even though the g.fin_id for those will then be blank because they have a e.char9_nme value of Null. How can I change the query to accomplish this?

[image: results here]

```
select 
      a.acct_id, 
      c.fld3_txt, 
      b.issue_loc1_cde,
      b.instr_id, 
      a.fld1_nme, 
      b.issue_cls2_nme, 
      g.fin_id, 
      e.char9_nme 

from position_dg as a
     inner join 
     infoportal..issue_dg as b on b.INSTR_ID = a.INSTR_ID
     inner join 
     InfoPortal..IVW_ACCT as c on a.acct_id = c.acct_id
     inner join 
     InfoPortal..DW_AcctCharDG as d on a.acct_id = d.acctid
     inner join 
     ACCUM_ISS_CHAR_HIST as e on a.instr_id = e.instr_id
     inner join 
     MD_FINANCIAL_ENTITY as f on e.char9_nme = f.fin_enty_name 
     inner join md_FINANCIAL_ENTITY_ALTERNATE_IDENTIFIER as g on 
                f.fin_enty_id = g.fin_enty_id
                and b.MAT_EXP_DTE > getdate()
                and b.issue_cls1_nme = 'Derivatives'
                and a.as_of_tms >= getdate()-1
                and b.iss_typ in ('FFX','IRS','EQF')
                and d.AcctChrSetId = 'DerivativeRpt'
                and d.EndTms IS NULL
                and a.acct_id = 'FOGEMBLCR'
                and g.id_ctxt_typ = 'LEGAL_ENTITY_IDENTIFIER'
                and e.as_of_dte = (
                                   select MAX (as_of_dte)-1 
                                   from accum_iss_char_hist
                                  )
```

I expect the results to show fin_id records for some ond blank fin_id records for some, but at the moment only the ones with a fin_id record is hown and the rest is excluded from the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a left join.

Join all those tables (last 3 as you said) as left join. For better clarity I have moved conditions of every tables in their ON clause and for base table `a` made a where clause.

```
select 
      a.acct_id, 
      c.fld3_txt, 
      b.issue_loc1_cde, 
      b.instr_id, 
      a.fld1_nme, 
      b.issue_cls2_nme, 
      g.fin_id, 
      e.char9_nme 

from  position_dg as a
      inner join
      infoportal..issue_dg as b on b.INSTR_ID = a.INSTR_ID 
                                   and b.MAT_EXP_DTE > getdate()
                                   and b.issue_cls1_nme = 'Derivatives'
                                   and b.iss_typ in ('FFX','IRS','EQF')
      inner join 
      InfoPortal..IVW_ACCT as c on a.acct_id = c.acct_id
      inner join 
      InfoPortal..DW_AcctCharDG as d on a.acct_id = d.acctid
                                     and d.AcctChrSetId = 'DerivativeRpt'
                                     and d.EndTms IS NULL
      left join 
      ACCUM_ISS_CHAR_HIST as e on a.instr_id = e.instr_id 
                               and e.as_of_dte = (
                                         select MAX (as_of_dte)-1 
                                         from accum_iss_char_hist
                                                  )
      left join 
      MD_FINANCIAL_ENTITY as f on e.char9_nme = f.fin_enty_name 
      left join 
      md_FINANCIAL_ENTITY_ALTERNATE_IDENTIFIER as g on f.fin_enty_id = g.fin_enty_id 
                                          and g.id_ctxt_typ = 'LEGAL_ENTITY_IDENTIFIER'
Where a.as_of_tms >= getdate()-1
      and a.acct_id = 'FOGEMBLCR'
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @GLOBALJJ . . . If this answers the question, you should consider accepting the answer.  Not accepting it suggests that you are waiting for a better answer.